# Java Swing JTree is not garbage collected

Tags: java, swing, memory, garbage-collection, memory-leaks

The following demo app creates a JFrame with a JInternalFrame (MDI interface). The internal frame features a JTree, with a JTree model. To simulate a large model, a 10MB buffer is associated to the JTree model. When the internal frame is closed (disposed), the JTree and its model will never be garbage collected.

jvisualvm shows the reason -- some static Swing class fields will keep references to the JTree. Unlike other Swing memory leaks no event handler is used here.

Is this a bug? Is there a clean solution collecting the disposed internal frame, its tree and its model (besides workarounds like using weak references, nullifying the data in the JTree model)?

```
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;

public class Test extends javax.swing.JFrame {

   public Test() {
      javax.swing.JDesktopPane jDesktopPane = new javax.swing.JDesktopPane();
      setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setContentPane(jDesktopPane);
      InternalTreeFrame f = new InternalTreeFrame();
      jDesktopPane.add(f);
      f.show();
      pack();
      setBounds(10, 10, 400, 300);
   }

   public class InternalTreeFrame extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {
      public InternalTreeFrame() {
  javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
  javax.swing.JTree jTree = new javax.swing.JTree();
  jScrollPane.setViewportView(jTree);
  jTree.setModel(new DefaultTreeModel(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new LargeObject("big root"))));
  setContentPane(jScrollPane);
  setClosable(true);
     setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
  pack();
  setBounds(10, 10, 300, 200);
      }
   }

   // 10MB helper object, easy to spot in visual vm heap dump
   public class LargeObject {
      public LargeObject(String name) {
  this.name = name;
  buff = new byte[1024*1024*10];
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
  return name;
      }

      private final String name;
      private final byte[] buff;
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
     new Test().setVisible(true);
  }
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is a bug, but a solution would be to set an empty model into the JTree in the windowClosing() event of the (internal) frame

Comment: Thanks! Yes, a workaround of this sort is actually what I'm currently using. I've implemented a custom dispose() method which calls super.dispose() and drops the references to the large data items in the tree model. I've just asked myself, if there is a cleaner approach to this issue.

Answer (score 2):

There is a known [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4759312) in the JDK about the last JInternalFrame not being garbage collected correctly on `dispose`. This is because the `JDesktopPane` maintains a `framesCache` which holds references to the JInternalFrames. This cache is not refreshed when the last JInternalFrame is closed.

The workaround is to force the cache to reload by calling `JDesktopPane.selectFrame`, as shown below:

```
    f.addInternalFrameListener(new InternalFrameAdapter() {
        public void internalFrameClosed(InternalFrameEvent e) {
            jDesktopPane.selectFrame(true);
        }
    });
```

Try it out and you will see memory reclaimed once the JInternalFrame is closed.

Comment: Thank, I've tried this out. First I modified the test case to create 10 internal frames. Closing all of them I see two instances of TreeModel which are not reclaimed. One is referenced from JDesktopPane's framesCache, and one from a static field in CompositionAreaHandler. Using the cache reload approach the instance referenced by framesCache is reclaimed, but the other one still remains.